# Is this integral possible? $\int \frac{e^{-e^{x}}}{x^2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How could I get to integrate this? Not anything I know has taken me anywhere.

I think what everyone would try first is pretty obvious.

$$\int \frac{e^{-e^{x}}}{x^2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$

if I integrate by parts:

$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-e^{x}}+\int\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-e^{x}+x}dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I highly doubt the indefinite integral has a closed form. [WA is unsurprisingly clueless](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5E%5B-e%5Ex%5Dsin%5B1%2Fx%5D%2Fx%5E2&dataset=). How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: it was in a calculus 2 worksheet. the only problem i couldn't get an answer for

Comment: If it was on a worksheet, then perhaps there is more to the question?

Comment: Try a Taylor series, or a couple, that you learn at the end of Calculus 2 for $\sin(x)$ or $e^x$

Comment: there's no closed form with elementary functions

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer along with some speculation. Your integral cannot be integrated by standard calc II methods, and you likely made a mistake transcribing it here or misread the integral.

$\sin(\frac1x)$ is disgusting so let's get rid of the inside first.
$$u=\frac1x,\quad \frac{du}{dx}=-\frac1{x^2},\quad dx=-x^2du,\quad x=\frac1u$$
$$\int \frac{e^{-e^{x}}}{x^2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\rightarrow\int -e^{-e^{\frac1u}}\sin{u}du$$
We cannot proceed further with only calc II methods. I suspect your integral may instead be $$\int \frac{e^{-\frac1x}}{x^2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$ or something similar, wherein it is possible to approach by integration by parts.

If this answer is not helpful I'll delete it :)